# How to fix Angular FormArray Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, formarray

I try create react form with form array. However I get an error: "Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute".

I looked this site
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

I tried few solution from other questions from stack overflow but it didn't work for me.(It might because of my poor knowledge)

Following are that I tried to fix error.

'injury-condition-found.component.html'

1. [formGroup]="injuryFoundForm" => formGroup="injuryFoundForm".
2. [formGroupName]="i" => formGroupName="i"

'detail-injury-form.component.html'

3. [formGroup]="detailInjuryForm" => formGroup="detailInjuryForm"

Here is my code

'injury-condition-found.component.ts'

```
export class InjuryConditionFoundComponent implements OnInit { 
injuryFoundForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * Create Form group
     */
    this.injuryFoundForm = this.fb.group({
      noInjury: false,
      details: this.fb.array([
        this.initDetail()
      ])
    });
  }

  initDetail(){
    return this.fb.group({
      treatment: null,
      unknown: null
    });
  }

  addDetail(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.injuryFoundForm.controls['details'];
    control.push(this.initDetail());
  }

  deleteDetail(i: number){
    const control = <FormArray>this.injuryFoundForm.controls['details'];
    control.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

'injury-condition-found.component.html'

```
<div [formGroup]="injuryFoundForm">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="noInjury"></mat-checkbox>

    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let item of injuryFoundForm.controls.details.controls">
        <app-detail-injury-form 
            [group]="injuryFoundForm.controls.details.controls[i]"
            (deleteClicked)="deleteInjuryForm(i)">
        </app-detail-injury-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

'detail-injury-form.component.ts'

```
export class DetailInjuryFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() deleteClicked: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
    @Input('group') public detailInjuryForm: FormGroup;

    deleteDetailInjury(){
        this.deleteClicked.emit(this.id);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.detailInjuryForm = this.fb.group({
            treatment: null,
            unknown: null
        });
    }
}
```

'detail-injury-form.component.html'

```
<mat-accordion [formGroup]="detailInjuryForm">
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                <button (click)="deleteDetailInjury()">Delete</button>
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <label>Unknown Behavior</label>
        <textarea rows="4" formControlName="unknown"></textarea>

        <label>Treatment Notes</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" formControlName="treatment"></textarea>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

I am new developer and sorry for my mess code.
My project have more code but I cut code where are not important for this question.
Kind regards

Comment: There appear to be many inconsistencies in your code. For example, `deleteInjuryForm(i)` is never defined in a ts file. Also this `<div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let item of injuryFoundForm.controls.details.controls">` makes no sense. You need to add `i = index` in your `ngFor` and You cannot reference `i` on the same `div` as your `ngFor`. You should reference `i` in a child element. Further, why are you trying to name a formGroup `i` anyway? `injuryFoundForm` is a FormGroup not a FormArray.

Comment: Thank you for asking and I fixed the error.

<div *ngFor="let item of injuryFoundForm.controls.details.controls; let i = index">
     <app-detail-injury-form 
         [group]="injuryFoundForm.controls.details.controls[i]" 
         (deleteClicked)="deleteDetail(i)">
    </app-detail-injury-form>
</div>

This code works!!

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks guys. This problem has been solved.